# How to handle GRPC Golang High CPU Usage

Tags: go, grpc, cpu, cpu-usage

We have suspicious high cpu usage in our golang function that we using grpc to stream our transaction. The function is simple, when we got request of ORDER ID data changes from frontend, then we consume and stream back.

Here the code

```
func (consumer OrderChangesConsumer) Serve(message string) {
    response := messages.OrderChanges{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &response); err != nil {
        logData := map[string]interface{}{
            "message": message,
        }
        seelog.Error(commonServices.GenerateLog("parse_message_error", err.Error(), &logData))
    }

    if response.OrderID > 0 {
        services.PublishChanges(response.OrderID, &response)
    }
}




// PublishChanges sends the order change message to the changes channel.
func PublishChanges(orderID int, orderChanges *messages.OrderChanges) {
    orderMutex.RLock()
    defer orderMutex.RUnlock()
    orderChan, ok := orderChans[orderID]
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    orderChan <- orderChanges
}
```

[image: pprof]

How we can improve and test the best practice for this case?

Comment: Is it strictly needed to be holding the lock when you write to the `orderChan`? If you unlock explicitly before you test for `ok` do things go more smoothly? The channel write may block which leaves the code holding the lock as it is.

Comment: Some thoughts: Serve is not a pointer receiver method, so OrderChangesConsumer is being copied on every invocation. Message is also copied when converted to []byte so if messages are large you are spending a lot of time copying them. You also should unlock your mutex before pushing into the channel.

Comment: @jdizzle Go is COW for copied values so I think this wouldn't see the copy hit? I also thought the compiler was a little more clever about []byte to string conversions, less certain about that one though.

Comment: checked, the compiler is not that clever about byte copying and this is likely calling runtime.slicebytetostring, which indeed just copies the bytes. 

I will say that since the resulting byte slice is being read byte-by-byte in the json parse the performance hit of the byte slice copy is likely much less than the overhead of json unmarshalling.

Answer (score 1):

Would update your PublishChanges code to the following and see if that helps:

```golang
// PublishChanges sends the order change message to the changes channel.
func PublishChanges(orderID int, orderChanges *messages.OrderChanges) {
    orderMutex.RLock()
    orderChan, ok := orderChans[orderID]
    orderMutex.RUnlock()
    if !ok {        
        return
    }
    orderChan <- orderChanges
}
```

You might also want to consider using `sync.Map` for an easier to use concurrent map.

Comment: so without defer?

Comment: Correct. The channel push could take a long time and park the go routine. If you’re holding the lock then you could cause excess collisions on the lock and thrashing on sleep/wake or spinning on the lock.

Comment: how if the channel run with go func()? like `go func() { orderChan <- orderChanges }()`